# Ошибка Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Я учусь создавать приложения на Андроид. В данный момент я пытаюсь создать регистрацию пользователя. Для начала я подключила firebase к своему проекту и добавила все необходимые функции, программа скомпилировалась, мне удалось заполнить все поля, но появилась следующая ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.company.android.myapplication, PID: 27432
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.company.android.myapplication.RegistrationActivity.userRegistration(RegistrationActivity.java:234)
        at com.company.android.myapplication.RegistrationActivity.access$600(RegistrationActivity.java:38)
        at com.company.android.myapplication.RegistrationActivity$3.onClick(RegistrationActivity.java:135)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7192)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7166)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:824)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27592)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Ниже находится сам код:

```
private EditText emailEt, passwordEt, nameEt, surnameEt, loginEt, passwordEt2;
    private Button regBut;
    private TextView mDisplayDate;
    private RadioButton maleRadio, femaleRadio;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
//Used in cases where the user needs to show that the program is not frozen, doing the ongoing work.
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private FirebaseMethods mFirebaseMethods;
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    private String name, surname, email, password, password2, login, birthDateStr, gender;
    //private final String email = "";
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth, mAuth;
    private final DateTimeFormatter mDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        
        actionBar.setTitle("Create Account");
        //enable back button
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        emailEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEt);
        passwordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEt);
        passwordEt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordEt2);
        nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEt);
        surnameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.surnameEt);
        loginEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEt);
        regBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regbutton);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showDate);
        maleRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleButton);
        femaleRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleButton);


        mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                        RegistrationActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_MinWidth, mDateSetListener, year, month, day);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                birthDateStr =  String.format("%02d-%02d-%d", dayOfMonth, month, year);
                mDisplayDate.setText(birthDateStr);
            }
        };



        regBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = emailEt.getText().toString().trim();//getText return a Text which Text view display
                String password =passwordEt.getText().toString().trim();
                String password2 = passwordEt2.getText().toString().trim();

                if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
                {
                    //set error and focus to email
                    emailEt.setError("Invalid email");
                    emailEt.setFocusable(true);
                }else if(!isValid(password))
                {
                    passwordEt.setError("Incorrect password");
                    passwordEt.setFocusable(true);
                }/*else if(!password.equals(password2))
                {
                    passwordEt2.setError("Passwords are not identical");
                    passwordEt2.setFocusable(true);
                }else if(!nameIsValid() || !surnameIsValid())
                {
                    return;
                }else if(!checkDate())
                {
                    //return;
                }*/
                else
                {
                    //mFirebaseMethods.registerNewUser(password, email);
                    userRegistration(email, password);
                    //mFirebaseMethods.registerNewUser(name, surname, email, password, gender,
                           //login, birthDate);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean chooseGender()
    {
        if(maleRadio.isChecked())
        {
            gender = "Male";
            return true;
        }

        if(femaleRadio.isChecked())
        {
            gender = "Female";
            return true;
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Select your gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkDate()
    {
        LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
        birthDate = LocalDate.parse(birthDateStr);
        Period age = Period.between(currentDate, birthDate);

        if(age.getYears() < 16)
        {
            mDisplayDate.setError("Your age must be 16 or older");
            mDisplayDate.setFocusable(true);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean nameIsValid()
    {
        name = nameEt.getText().toString().trim();
        if(name.isEmpty()) {
            nameEt.setError("This field cannot be empty");
            nameEt.setFocusable(true);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean surnameIsValid()
    {
        surname = surnameEt.getText().toString().trim();
        if(surname.isEmpty()) {
            surnameEt.setError("This field cannot be empty");
            surnameEt.setFocusable(true);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void userRegistration(final String email, String password)
    {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        } else {
                      
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public boolean isValid(final String password)
    {
        Pattern pattern;
        Matcher matcher;

        final String PASS_DEM = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{4,}$";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(PASS_DEM);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
        if(!matcher.matches())
            return false;
        else if(password.isEmpty())
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp()
    {
        onBackPressed(); //go previous activity
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у Вас происходит обращение к методу сохранения с какой то неинициализированной строкой (емейла или пароля?). Почему - непонятно, потму что строки, в котрых Вы получаете из формы и сравниваете между собой пароли - вроде бы, правильные. Думаю, навдо поотлаживаться: встать на точку ДО выхова метода, который вызывает ошибку, и посмотреть, какое значение имеет сответствующая переменная

Comment: А, я, кажется, догадался! в начале метода userRegistration() происходит обращение к методу createUserWithEmailAndPassword() переменной mAuth. А создания экземпляра mAuth нигде не видно. Вот и получается null pointer exception.

Comment: @S.H.Блин, точно. Спасибо большое. Уже столько времени потратила и не замечала этого

Answer (score 1):

в начале метода userRegistration() происходит обращение к методу createUserWithEmailAndPassword() переменной mAuth. А создания экземпляра mAuth нигде не видно. Вот и получается null pointer exception